# Return a 404 code

Tags: angularjs

Here is my php code

```
http_response_code(404);
$message = http_response_code()." No data found";
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($message);
```

Here is my AngularJS code

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.element = function(num){
        var element_id = num;//num;  
        $http.get("customers.php",{params:{"id":element_id}}).then(function (response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data;
        }
        ,function errorCallback(response){
            $scope.error=response.data;

        });

    };

});
```

How do I return the 404 code, or at least load a new page to display it?

Comment: $data is supposed to be $message

Comment: You would handle the error response in the `errorCallback`. You can get the HTTP status code via `response.status`